# Parallel write to / read from file

Tags: io, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

From briefly looking online, I couldn't find a method for reading from or writing to a file in Fortran 90 using OpenMP in parallel. I want to know if it is possible to do something like

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
do i=1,Nx
do j=1,Ny
do k=1,Nz
read(1,*) B(i,j,k)
enddo
enddo
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL

!$OMP PARALLEL
do i=1,Nx
do j=1,Ny
do k=1,Nz
write(1,*) B(i,j,k)
enddo
enddo
enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Where there are additional clauses to ensure that this is done correctly. I imagine there may be an easy way to do this for the read, but the write seems less obvious. Thanks for any and all help/suggestions!

Comment: Fortran tag instead of fortran90 will bring you more attentions. Do not use version specific tag without the generic one.

Comment: Even if it was possible, the disk access is the bottleneck, more cores won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing formatted io, think about how thread N figures out the correct offset in the file to read/write.

Additionally, since the question is tagged gfortran, in gfortran there is a per-unit mutex which is held for the duration of a io statement.